# Return an element at a given position (but it doesn't start at that position!)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to return an element with a given left position.

lets say i have the following:

```
<ul class="first" style="width:840px;left:-60px;"></ul>
<ul class="first" style="width:840px;left:0px;"></ul>
<ul class="first" style="width:840px;left:780px;"></ul>
```

I want to return the UL that is behind `left: 240px;`

```
var left = $('ul').filter(function() {
    return $(this).position().left == 240;
});
console.log(left);
```

I tried the above but it returns nothing!

Comment: How about after changing it to margin-left in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var behindsUL = $('.capture .captureButtons ul').filter(function() {
  var left = $(this).position().left;
  return left >= 240 AND left <= 280;
});
console.log(behindsUL);
```

Then you will not going far if there is an XML syntax conflict such '&&'...you should find a solution

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, we can't see any ul with a left position of 240px (60px, 0px, 780px), wich is what you are testing. What does mean 'behind some position' ? you mean less ? your code indicates strictly equal...

Comment: good eye for detail there yes i mean that is behind that position i guess it should be >= !

Comment: yes you guess right, just correct your test condition and it should works as you wish ;)

Comment: well this does work but using >= shows the element that is greater than or equal to the sum, how would i set it so it shows between ? i.e. 240 - 280 ?

Comment: `var left = $(this).position().left;
return left >= 240 && left <= 280;`

Comment: Invalid XML name
return $(this).position().left >= 240 && <= 280;

Is what console is returning i tried that already !

Comment: yes I wrote a mistake, I corrected it, try again
`var left = $(this).position().left; return left >= 240 && left <= 280;`

Comment: @Xaview Wrap the script in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` or externalize the script. The problem is with the `&&` characters.

Comment: oh well it complicate things ;) if I remember well 'AND' is a correct workaround instead '&&' for ECMASCRIPT

Comment: again your example didn't work, im guessing it's how it's structured ?
`var left = $('.capture .captureButtons ul').filter(function() {
   $(this).position().left; return left >= 240 && left <= 280;
   }).attr('class');`

Comment: oh dude sorry there was another left var that confuse, please watch the new answer